# Application match

Tags: vba, loops, search, match

I’ve cobbled together some coding which is a bit of a dog, but almost does what I want it to do. I have a range of reference numbers in a worksheet, which I need to loop through and then to search through several other worksheets to find a matching ref number, a value and the name of the department where the ref number is processed (Let’s say the Ref number is Column P, Value is Column Q and Department Column R). It then creates a list on a new worksheet containing the above data. The below coding almost does what I want it do. It loops through the original ref number list, finds all matches and then creates a list on a new worksheet. However, I can’t figure out how to also return the Value and department names. I know I need to reference the application match value rather the original range as below but am not quite sure.  I hope the above makes sense and any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub HighlightMatches()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim var As Variant, iSheet As Integer, iRow As Long, iRowL As Long, bln     As    Boolean
Dim RS As Worksheet

FR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
Set RS = Sheets("S1")


iRowL = Sheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

For iRow = 1 To iRowL

If Not IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 16)) Then
For iSheet = ActiveSheet.Index + 1 To Worksheets.Count
        bln = False
        var = Application.match(Cells(iRow, 16).Value, Worksheets      (iSheet).Columns(16), 0)

        If Not IsError(var) Then
           bln = True
           Exit For
        End If
     Next iSheet
  End If


  If bln = False Then
     Cells(iRow, 16).Font.Bold = False
     Else
     ' I think the line below needs to be changed to reference the application.match
     Range(Cells(iRow, 16), Cells(iRow, 17)).Copy
     RS.Select
     Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlValues
     Sheets("FPFCLaims").Select
  End If
  Next iRow
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Matt, I'd be happy to help, so what is the problem with the match? Match works like this - worksheetfunction.match("search", rs.rows(1),0). That will retrieve the number, in terms of the location, where the search item has been found.

Comment: Hi Lowpar, the match aspect is working fine, I need to it return the offset values of the next 2 columns with the match value. Thanks for the help

Comment: Could you store them in a variable and then later set the range to the values? Also, I find the line ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(iRow, 16), Cells(iRow, 17)).Copy Destination:=rs.Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) would be better.

Comment: I'm not quite sure to be honest. What I need in essence is the offset values from the matched cell. This line var = Application.match(Cells(iRow, 16).Value, Worksheets(iSheet).Columns(16), 0) finds the matching values, I need to return the offset from the worksheets(isheet) if you follow me.

Comment: You can use Application.match(Cells(iRow, 16).Value, Worksheets(iSheet).Columns(16), 0) in order to feed the column, so you could go cell(iRow, Application.match(Cells(iRow, 16).Value, Worksheets(iSheet).Columns(16), 0) + 1) to get the offset of one, on the column level.

Comment: I've entered the above line her in my codes. It seems to bring random values back. Am I missing something? End If
      If bln = False Then
         Cells(iRow, 16).Font.Bold = False
         Else
         Cells(iRow, Application.match(Cells(iRow, 16).Value, Worksheets(iSheet).Columns(16), 0) + 1).Copy
         RS.Select
         Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlValues
         Sheets(3).Select
      End If
   Next iRow

Comment: also does cells(irow, application.match need to be cells(irow,16, application.match? Many thanks